# Building accessories for a Powerstar LiFe battery

Tags: power-supply, power

I have a Powerstar LiFE battery with 4 pin XLR outputs. The outputs are listed as being 8 amp outputs and 3.5 amp outputs. Does this mean that they will output up to 8 and 3.5 amps or does this mean that they are "presenting" 8 and 3.5 amps; that is, is there any way to know if current is always present at the output or if current is regulated based on load?

Answer (score 1):

The current ratings of a power source are the maximum the source can supply.  The actual current delivered to a load is determined by the load (unless the load wants more current than the supply can deliver.)

(There are "constant current" power supplies where the supply attempts to deliver the specified current - these may be used to power LEDs and some other specialized applications.  These supplies are fairly rare, and should be clearly labelled.)